# Cannot find "DynamoDB" in Service Provider in External Data Store Service Import while I am trying to use DynamoDB in geneXus?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, genexus

I am beginner in Genexus and have a bit of knowledge in AWS services.

I wanted to connect GeneXus with AWS DynamoDB and tried to follow [this link](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?50498,DynamoDB%20Support%20in%20GeneXus) steps, but I couldn't find "DynamoDB" in Service Provider Dropdown where only "OData" is available.

I am using GeneXus 17 Version 17.0.158023 U8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need GeneXus 18, as this link explains
https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac?data=51777;;